# Cakephp Find all WHERE in two categories

Tags: php, cakephp, find, cakephp-2.3

I have trouble finding items that belong to two or more categories in `cakephp 2`.

In my Controller I have the following:

```
$kategories = array(1,2);
$options['conditions'] = array('Categorie.id' => $kategories);
$items = $this->Item->find('all',$options);
```

The query above shows all Items that have either associated category-id 1 or 2.

**How can I search for all items, that belong to `category.id 1` AND `2` (not OR).**

I tried using the 'AND' array with no luck:

```
$options['conditions'] = array('AND' => array('Categorie.id' => $kategories));
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked a little further on this and found the solution:

To find all items, that belong to category.id 1 AND 2 (not OR) I just had to add a 'group' parameter to my find like this:

```
$options['group'] = array('Item.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Categorie.id) > 1');
```

The complete query (working):

```
$kategories = array(1,2);
$options['conditions'] = array('Categorie.id' => $kategories);
$options['group'] = array('Item.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Categorie.id) > 1');
$items = $this->Item->find('all',$options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN` operator:

```
$options['conditions'] = array('Categorie.id IN' => $kategories);
```

Or in that case if you always want to look for this two categories use `AND`:

```
$options['conditions'] = array('AND' => array(
    array('Categorie.id' => $kategories[0]),
    array('Categorie.id' => $kategories[1])
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$kategories = array(1,2);
$kategories = implode(',',$kategories );


 $options['conditions'] = array('Categorie.id in ( ' . $kategories . ' )') ;
 $items = $this->Item->find('all',$options);
```